# Фильтрация записей в db.query(.) по нескольким полям

Tags: запрос, android, sqlite

Привет. Стал такой вопрос. Как можно сделать фильтрацию записей по нескольким параметрам.
Допустим, имеется 1 таблица с записями. Таким кодом фильтрую записи по категориям

```
where = "category = ?"
whereParam = "Сны"

Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, where, whereParam, null, null, null);
```

Но допустим мне необходимо сделать фильтрацию по 2 полям "category" и "smile".
То есть из всех записей фильтруются записи с категорией "Сны" а потом из этих записей фильтруются записи со smile = "хорошо"

Как это можно сделать более легким путем?

Answer (score 2):

```
String where = "category = ? and smile=?";
String[] whereParam = {"Сны", "Хорошо"};
Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, where, whereParam, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE category = "сны" AND smile = "хорошо"
```

Вообще, категории и оценки искать строчными не есть хорошо. Уж оценки можно легко переделать на 1-5 интотвые значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlQuery = "select * from mytable where category like 'сны%' and smile like 'хорошо%'";
return db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

rawQuery дает больше возможностей